# What is the cost to store 1KB, 10KB, 100KB worth of data into the ethereum blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, storage

Whatever is stored in the blockchain is immutable which means I can fetch this data back in the future. As of today (2016-feb),

- How does one store a 1kb, 10kb, or 100kb or arbitary data/text in the ethereum blockchain? What is the code needed to do this?
- Once stored how do you download the data back onto your desktop?
- How much would this cost exactly in ether/gas/fiat at todays prices?

Comment: It's better to split this up in multiple questions on stack exchange. Asking many questions in 1 thread is usually not good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here is an article](https://blockgeeks.com/guides/ethereum-gas-step-by-step-guide/) to describe everything about gas and how to calculate it.

> Suppose, we are adding two numbers and for that the contract must do
> the following actions:
>
> Storing 10 in a variable. Let’s say this operation costs 45 gas.
> Adding two variables, let’s say this costs 10 gas. Storing the result
> which again costs 45 gas.
>
> Suppose the sender specifies a gas limit of 120 gas.
>
> The total gas used by the miner to run the computation is (45+10+45) =
> 100 gas.
>
> The fee that is owed to the miner, assuming 1 gas costs 20 Gwei, is
> (100 * 20 Gwei) = 0.000002 ETH.

And [here](https://ethgasstation.info/) you can get GAS calculations

Comment: This answer is underrated.

Answer (score 84):

**tl;dr: $0.076/KB or $76,000/GB**

According to the [yellow paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf), the fee is 20k gas to store a 256 bit word. A kilobyte is thus 640k gas.

Gas right now is around 50 Gwei (0.00000005 ETH). So a KB of storage costs 0.032 ETH. A GB costs 32,000 ETH.

To test this empirically, I created a contract with this code:

```
contract test {
    bytes data;

    function addData(bytes _data) public {
        data = _data;
    }

}
```

at address [transaction](https://live.ether.camp/account/1dca675c7864fde87fa32138156eded3a22f870f).

Then I sent a [transaction](https://live.ether.camp/account/1dca675c7864fde87fa32138156eded3a22f870f) adding 1KB of data ("0x111111...." 2k times).

This transaction took 753,072 gas (0.03765 ETH at current prices).

It costs about 0.003 ETH to call the contract without adding any data, so that equates to about 0.035 ETH per KB ($0.076), or around $76,000 USD per GB of storage.

Retrieving this data is free, though.

Comment: "It costs about 0.003 ETH to call the contract without adding any data, so that equates to about 0.035 ETH per kb ($0.076), or around $76,000 USD per GB of storage." Does this mean it cost $0.076 per KB you want to add to the contract, so lets say i have a contract that holds 2 GB of data and i want to add 5 KB to it. does this mean it will cost me $0.38 or $375000.38 ??

Comment: It will only cost `$0.38`. Fees are incurred only when you set a zero-byte to a non zero value.

Comment: so technically a contract could hold a whole database and be 5 GB of size the only thing that will cost is to add data to such database ? Retrieving that data should be free ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There's very few use cases that I can think of that require holding so much data on-chain, though.

Comment: lets say hold anonymized medical records ided by only hash ?

Comment: Right. But you probably don't actually need to store every hash on-chain. You could just store the root of a merkle tree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49670/discussion-between-remi-and-tjaden-hess).

Comment: What a difference 14 months make. Today (4/24/2017), 0.035 ETH costs $1.75 at the price of ~$50 per ETH. That puts the cost of 1GB of storage at $1,750,000, i.e. 1.75 million dollars, instead of the $76,000 that it was 14 months ago (in Feb 2016)

Comment: Today, with 1ETH = USD 311 (apron.), it would exceed USD 10 mil!!

Comment: Is there an easy way to find out current cost per unit of data?

Comment: @TjadenHess first you say that calling the contract costs ether then at the end you say retrieving data is free?

Comment: "call" here means in the sense of actually sending a transaction that interacts with the blockchain and "calls" a function, not in the web3 sense of reading from local state without sending a transaction

Comment: Is anyone looking at this in 2021 where ETH is now worth $2000, would equate to a much much higher price, close to $100 million per GB if not more actually since has prices are crazy at the moment

Comment: Should be 233M$/GB as of right now with 200 Gwei average gas prices and 1823$/ETH

Answer (score 15):

I wanted to give a quick update on this topic. (The other answers with prices are kinda outdated).

Same as the other answer a kilobyte of data is 640k gas.

But in contrast to two years ago the gas price in 2019 is ~10 gwei instead of 50 gwei.

However the price of ETH also increased.

**Two years ago** it would cost you **$0.076/KB**.

In **August 2019** it costed you **$1.204/KB**.

As of **23.07.2020** the gas price spiked to 80 gwei so the storage now costs **$13.82/KB**!

Answer (score 1):

> Once stored how do you download the data back onto your desktop?

Every Ethereum transaction is publicly viewable. All you need is a viewer. [Like this one for example.](https://www.etherchain.org)

[image]

> How much would this cost exactly in ether/gas/fiat at todays prices?

It doesn't work like that.

[You can fetch in real time, the current transaction pricing data here.](https://ethgasstation.info/index.php)

[image]

Your question implies a centralized pricing model. For example, in traditional centralized transactions (e.g., credit cards, wire transfers, ECH, etc.), the price is set by the payment processor. But the Ethereum network is decentralized. So it works in reverse fashion compared to the centralized model.

There is no single payment processor. Instead, there is a network of competing processors called "miners." Miners invest computing time and resources necessary to solve the math problem required to confirm and complete any given transaction.

Under this model, the sender sets the price with an offer to the network (miners). The Ethereum network responds to the price offered (which is a defacto incentive for the miners to solve the math problem necessary to hash a block) with a transaction. The time it takes to complete a transaction is correlated to the inverse of the price offered by the sender. i.e., The higher the price offered, the more priority that transaction will receive by the miners and, therefore, the less time the transaction will take to complete.

The above site tracks and reports the current transaction times at common given price points.

Answer (score -1):

It is expensive on Ethereum mainnet. However, on side chain (polygon, e.g.) or L2 (zkSync, Arbitrum/Optimism), the cost can be greatly reduced.
Meanwhile, you can choose low gas fee hours. It's additional 80% discount.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question how much it costs.