# Can a contract listen to events of another contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, web3js, events, logs

I read that to listen to events you need to use web3.js. Are there other ways of doing it? Can a contract even somehow listen to events of another contract? Thanks!

Comment: Today, you can use an oracle eg https://docs.chain.link/architecture-overview/architecture-request-model#off-chain-oracle-node

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A contract cannot listen to events of another contract.  From [Solidity docs:](http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contracts.html#events)

> Log and event data is not accessible from within contracts (not even
>   from the contract that created a log).

web3.js is a wrapper around JSON-RPC, so another way of accessing event data is via "filters" in JSON-RPC such as [eth_newFilter.](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_newfilter)

Note the dichotomy that a contract can't access events and web3.js is needed, but web3.js can't access return values from a contract invocation.  So a pattern of using both an event and a return value like this may be needed:

```
event FooEvent(uint256 n);
function foo() returns (uint256) {
  FooEvent(1337);
  return 1337;
}
```

Comment: What is the javascript web3 code for event listening?

Comment: @JustinThomas 
```const instance = Web3.eth.contract(ABI).at(ADDRESS);
instance.FooEvent().watch((err, response) => { console.log (response); })
```

Comment: @JustinThomas IMHO event listening APIs are the least clear and there are several ways of achieving the same thing.  For other options to Raghav's comment, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/how-to-access-the-event-log-by-knowing-the-contract-address-web3 may help.

Comment: listening events using these lib can be risky as you may miss some events when some unexpected error occurs. best way to deal with such a flow is to make a loop and rather grab logs from the target contract

Comment: Looks like it may become possible in new Solidity versions - https://soliditylang.org/blog/2023/07/19/solidity-0.8.21-release-announcement/

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to just come out and say No, a contract cannot listen for events from another contract.  Solidity has `emit('event')` to emit events, but lacks `on('event')` for listening to events.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to ETH's answer.

Blockchains use State Tries to store state, and are as such, poor databases. Storing(and as a consequence, listening to) events is [extremely expensive](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/872/what-is-the-cost-to-store-1kb-10kb-100kb-worth-of-data-into-the-ethereum-block) (ABOUT $73,000 for a Gigabyte of storage).

**And if you can't store events, you can't listen to them**. Most blockchains I'm aware of don't even give you access to store emitted events as a result of this