# Read args object from particular block transaction in truffle console.

Tags: truffle, blockchain, logs

Hi I have question on how to read args from specific block transaction that are passed when event was called. I have triggered an event, my block is created and i got transaction tx. In the ' **Logs:** ' segment I have '**args:**' (on the bottom of image) which are stated as 
'**[object]**'. I want to read/print arguments on truffle console that are passed to this votedEvent if it is possible. What are the commands and what is the logic behind it.

I'm sorry but I have copied an image because I consider this to be more readable and much easier for me than formating. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This has been explained here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16313/how-can-i-view-event-logs-for-an-ethereum-contract