# High level tool (autogenerated UI) to obtain all the events emitted by the contract?

Tags: dapp-development, events, tools

I'm pretty sure something like this exists, saw it somewhere in the wild, my Google skills need some StackOverflow boost...

I would like to provide two data points:

- contract address
- name of the event

**The tool automagically fetches the data for me in a nice table.**

Concrete example:

- https://tokens.kleros.io/
- https://etherscan.io/address/0xEbcf3bcA271B26ae4B162Ba560e243055Af0E679#code
- give me all `DisputeCreation`

---

#### Or maybe possible directly in Etherscan?

[image]

> Search and filter Event Logs for this Address by BlockNo or Topic0 Hash

Unsure how to get all `DisputeCreation`?

---

**EDIT:** There are some solutions via code: [How can I view event logs for an ethereum contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16313/how-can-i-view-event-logs-for-an-ethereum-contract)

I did something like that in the past, I'm much more interested in an app that allows me much faster experimentation without prerequesites.

Comment: what does "without prerequisites" mean? If the solutions can be found here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16313/how-can-i-view-event-logs-for-an-ethereum-contract what are you looking for instead?

Comment: @PatrickCollins "without prerequesites" - no node.js, no command line, no writing software, no deploying code. Insert contract address and even name - generate the event list for me.

Comment: An answer from a Discord channel: *"yeah, could try the playground for kleros here https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraph/napolean0/kleros "*

Answer (score 0):

Reading all events from a contract is not very complex, but what you always need is the ABI of the contract. Just the name will not be enough. In the case you have the ABI there a some additional limitations like the 10.000 events limit from infura.io.

A good starting point is the open source project [Ethereum-Event-Scan](https://github.com/MarkusSprunck/ethereum-event-scan). This code was developed to read all events from a contract in public permissioned blockchains (here Etherscan is not available). It is written in Typescript and Angular for the UI parts. You may take the event reading code for your own purpose (MIT License).

[image]

You may find a detailed description on [Software Engineering Candies](https://www.sw-engineering-candies.com/blog-1/Ethereum-Event-Explorer-for-Smart-Contracts)

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Ethereum-Event-Scan and SW Engineering Candies is my page.