# How do I get all logs for all time for a given contract using web3?

Tags: web3js, truffle, events

[This answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/how-to-access-the-event-log-by-knowing-the-contract-address-web3) worked when `filter.get` was not deprecated, but now I am not sure how to do the same thing with subscribe - `web3.eth.subscribe` hears new events and acts on them after I create the subscription, but I am not sure how to get old events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this (tested with web3.js v1.2.1):

```
async function getPastLogs(address, fromBlock, toBlock) {
    if (fromBlock <= toBlock) {
        try {
            const options = {
                address  : address,
                fromBlock: fromBlock,
                toBlock  : toBlock
            };
            return await web3.eth.getPastLogs(options);
        }
        catch (error) {
            const midBlock = (fromBlock + toBlock) >> 1;
            const arr1 = await getPastLogs(address, fromBlock, midBlock);
            const arr2 = await getPastLogs(address, midBlock + 1, toBlock);
            return [...arr1, ...arr2];
        }
    }
    return [];
}

...

const latest = await web3.eth.getBlock("latest");
const logs = await getPastLogs(yourContractAddress, 1, latest);
```

You can further optimize this by replacing `1` with your contract creation block number.

See more on function `web3.eth.getPastLogs` [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#getpastlogs).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get an old log doing this - but do you know if it only gives the most recent transaction's event? If I process several transactions (that all emit events) it only ever returns one event (this is doing `logs = await web3.eth.getPastLogs({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: latest})`

Comment: This might also be a ganache issue as I only see the most recent log in the ganache UI