# Query returned more than 10000 results with getPastEvents

Tags: web3js, infura

I am writing a function to sync all transactions on a particular contract from a particular account in my local database to build a dashboard for account owners. I need to fetch all the past transfer events from the blockchain but I am getting the error that the call returned more than 10000 results sync function

```
syncTransactions(contract_address, owner_address, max_block) {
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contract_address);
  const from_block = max_block - 1000 >= 0 ? max_block - 1000 : 0;
  contract.getPastEvents(
    "Transfer",
    {
      fromBlock: from_block,
      toBlock: max_block,
    },
    (err, events) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        // check if 'to' or 'from' is equal to owner_account, if yes, add it to local database
      }
      syncTransactions(contract_address, owner_address, from_block - 1);
    }
  );
}
```

I haven't gotten to the point of filtering transactions using the given owner account. How can I avoid this error? Is there a better way to do this?

P.S. I have tried using both https and web socket URLs provided by Infura but getting the same error.

Comment: You can try something similar to the suggestion in [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/79675/16043). Just replace `web3.eth.getPastLogs` with `contract.getPastEvents`, and apply all required subsequent fixes (input parameters, etc).

Comment: Iterate over smaller batches of blocks to retrieve smaller batches of events instead of asking for everything in one gulp.

Comment: This is by design.. infura limits log queries to the past 10,000 events