# Can a contract that receives a token know the origin of the tokens?

Tags: contract-development, dapp-development, tokens, events

Can a contract that receives a token know the origin of the tokens?

(Assuming the token follows the token standard.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On transfers, the [token standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20) fires:

`event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value)`

This can allow frontends and user interfaces to listen and show the sender (`_from`) of a token.

Since [a contract can't listen to events of another contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1895/42), a frontend could pass `_from` to the contract.

---

EDIT: For a contract to securely and trustlessly know the `_from` of a token, a frontend should pass to the contract a variation of a [Merkle state transition proof](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/11/15/merkling-in-ethereum):

> Essentially, it is a proof which make
>   the claim “if you run transaction T on the state with root S, the
>   result will be a state with root S', with log L and output O”

The contract could then verify the proof trustlessly and obtain the `_from`.

Otherwise, in simply passing `_from` instead of a proof, the contract has to trust the frontend, which is insecure for some usecases: for example, a [contract that returns tokens to the sender,](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/is-there-a-way-for-a-contract-to-automatically-return-tokens-sent-to-it) since an attacker could send a transaction to the contract first and trick the contract into "returning" the tokens to the attacker.