# Is there a way for a contract to automatically return tokens sent to it?

Tags: contract-development, tokens

Is there a way for a contract to automatically return tokens sent to it?

(Assuming the token follows the [token standard.](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not automatically. The way that tokens work is that your contract actually doesn't have tokens: another "TokenContract" has balances that say your contract has tokens. Your contract would have to transfer tokens, by invoking the TokenContract.  It is easiest to transfer tokens back to the TokenContract, and [more involved to send them back to the original sender.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3954/can-a-contract-that-receives-a-token-know-the-origin-of-the-tokens)