# Is it possible to be notified about errors in a production contract?

Tags: solidity, error

As a smart contract developer, is it possible to listen for errors or `throw`s that happen in the mainnet? The motivation for this question is from an analytics perspective.

Events don't work in this situation since [all effects are reverted](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4087/3118).

Comment: I really doubt it, but I'm hoping someone can prove me wrong!

Comment: An inefficient way would be to listen to all the transactions sent to your contract, get their receipt and see if status is `0x00`