# Listening to Events from another smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, events

I want to listen to an event from inside another (deployed) smart contract.

I am a complete noob to Ethereum and Solidity. So please excuse me for stupid questions, I might have misunderstood everything.

I want to listen to an event inside a deployed contract C1. And when a certain event takes place a want to call a function on another contract C2.

For example, there is a token called `Matryx Token`, Solidity code can be found here at [EtherScan.io](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0af44e2784637218dd1d32a322d44e603a8f0c6a#code)

In the Solidity code there is a `contract MintableToken is ReleasableToken`, inside that contract there is an event `event MintFinished();`.

How can I listen to this event and then call a function on another contract C2?

I am an experienced Swift developer. So I was thinking of writing this as a macOS app or iOS app. I found Geth, Go Ethereum, [mobile client](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) but it is a bit unclear how I can listen to events.

So maybe the easiest way would be to develop my own Solidity "program" (dApp?) and deploy it as a smart contract?

Where I would make most functions private or `onlyOwner`?

Is it possible to call a non `constant` nor `public` function on a smart contract (*C2*)?

I do not understand the answer given for this question (possible duplicate) 
[Can a contract listen to events of another contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1895/can-a-contract-listen-to-events-of-another-contract)

Comment: As the first line of the selected answer says "A contract cannot listen to events". You have to implement a service **outside** the blockchain which forward events to your contract.

Comment: Ismail i linked to that question myself, in the bottom of my question, but as I said I do not understand that answer.

Comment: The answer cannot be more clear "A contract cannot listen to events".

Comment: Thanks for that Ismail but what about my other questions? 

Comment: Everything in the blockchain is public, there's no private storage. A dapp usually is a web app that 'talk' to a Ethereum node to query a smart contract state and can create transactions on behalf of a user to modify the contract state. A smart contract is a code on the blockchain state that only is executed when someone send a message to it. You cannot do heavy computation, the storage space is expensive, and the amount of computation in a single transaction is limited. I'd suggest to search for already answered question and create separate ones if you have more doubts.

Answer (score 0):

I got good answers in comments from @ismail, thank you. But I am posting an answer here for references regarding my question:

#### Q: Is it possible to call a non constant nor public function on a smart contract?

> Everything that is inside a contract is visible to all external
>   observers. Making something private only prevents other contracts from
>   accessing and modifying the information, but it will still be visible
>   to the whole world outside of the blockchain.

Taken from [Solidity documentation here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html?highlight=private)

Comment: Use the button "Ask Question" to create a new question, and if you wish you can put a link to this question in the body. You are writing an answer instead and will not have much visibility.