# How does a plot "Gas price to call / memory allocated" looks like?

Tags: gas, arrays, memory, statistics

Pretty simple question: i.e. I have a dummy contract like this one:

```
contract simple {
    uint[] dataArray;

    function push_one_more() {
        dataArray.push(1);
    }
}
```

How does the cost of calling `push_one_more` function depends of the `dataArray` size? Is it line, quadratically or maybe even exponential correlation?

Comment: look at http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/872/what-is-the-cost-to-store-1kb-10kb-100kb-worth-of-data-into-the-ethereum-block