# Why Blockchain if its expensive

Tags: blockchain, ether, gas, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I was made to understand that blockchain indeed is expensive [(here)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10327/solidity-variable-storage-or-persistency/10338)

I understand the importance of blockchain, but we have been used to a system where the end user is given less burden to use the product.

will this not be a hinderance to take blockchain based products on higher scale?

Question2:
will it make any difference if we use a private blockchain?

Comment: Use reddit for open ended questions, this is a place where you get answers for technical problems.

Comment: maybe my definition of this platform was wrong, was curious to know more :)

Answer (score 4):

It is not recommended to use blockchain for everything. It should be used mainly to transfer values : coins, assets of all kinds, etc.

For everything else can be used any decentralized storage system like : ipfs (http://ipfs/io), swarm (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Swarm---distributed-preimage-archive) and so on.

Comment: It is subjective, that is why the question fell under `open ended` category.