# Storing string value in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Are there any restrictions on the length of the value that can be stored as type `string` in Solidity? I am trying to store a `string` value in the smart contract member field. The length comes to around 220 chars. If I reduce the string value to around 140 chars I am able to store it. Any more and it does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the problem is not about the string size but about the provided gas, the storage costs more gas as you store more data. so when you increase the string size increase the gas limit provided in your transaction. 
using the following example :

```
contract store{
string public storage_;

function store_it(string s){

    storage_=s;
}


}
```

I've provided a string with 220 character it costs me 774675 gas.

Comment: BTW, the documentation [defines](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#dynamically-sized-byte-array) string as arbitrary-length, which suggests that the gas cost is the only limiting factor here.

Comment: the storage cost is discussed in a related post https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/872/what-is-the-cost-to-store-1kb-10kb-100kb-worth-of-data-into-the-ethereum-block

Comment: @SergeiTikhomirov is there a way to limit the number of characters in the string?

Comment: If you limit to 255 characters, how expensive is it. As of this moment 774675 gas is around $0.00000000123888350025

Comment: @Lokiare where can I find information like how much 1 gas costs for example (except google. I tried)

Comment: @S. Goody its listed on the Ethereum site.