# How big of a data can be stored?

Tags: solidity, remix

So I'm new to this and trying to create contract to store Medical data.
Is there a preferred limit to store data on the blockchain?
And all of my function's gas requirement is over the limit. Is if because of the larger records? I have tried making smaller structures but still have same warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to store large amounts of data on the Ethereum network. It is costly and slows the network unnecessarily.

See [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/872/what-is-the-cost-to-store-1kb-10kb-100kb-worth-of-data-into-the-ethereum-block), for an analysis of the price of storing data on the Ethereum network. (Approximately $76,000/GB).

There are other projects, such as [Storj](https://storj.io/) or [IPFS](https://ipfs.io/), designed for decentralised data storage.

Comment: That price was calculated in 2016. The price updated to the actual price of the eth today would be around $16 per KB which would be something like $16k for GB

Comment: @mirg I think your cost are per mbyte, for 1gbyte was about $16M at a price of 450 USD/ether on Mar 27, 2018.

Comment: @Ismael I agree, it was a typo