# How do I build Dapp Application that Stores Images

Tags: solidity

I am building a Dapp application.  One of my use-cases is storing a large number of images.  How can I accomplish this on Ethereum?

My architecture /correct me if I am wrong includes
 DaPP(smartcontract) ---->Oraclize --->API ---->DB(mongo etc..)

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

It is not feasible to store images on-chain (see [What is the cost to store 1KB, 10KB, 100KB worth of data into the ethereum blockchain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/872/what-is-the-cost-to-store-1kb-10kb-100kb-worth-of-data-into-the-ethereum-block)).

In general, you would store the image off-chain (IPFS, Swarm, imagur, ...) and put the fingerprint (hash) of the image and link to it on-chain.