# Saving huge volumes of data in Ethereum

Tags: database

I would like to save daily prices of about 3000 items (about 2mb in size) on a public blockchain, and I would like to create a DAPP to retrieve the data. I am considering saving the data on Ethereum. I checked [this link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/872/what-is-the-cost-to-store-1kb-10kb-100kb-worth-of-data-into-the-ethereum-block) which said it would cost around $76000 to save about 1 GB worth of data, which is very expensive for me. Is Ethereum the right choice for this type of use case? Or Should I consider something else? Any suggestions?

Comment: The answer to this question will be divided into "Use Ethereum" by anyone who has Ether and "Use something else" by all the rest.

Comment: I am very new to blockchain, and I don't even know what alternatives exist. I just would like to know if Ethereum is good for this type of use case, or if not, any suggested technologies or platforms that I should consider.

Comment: Depends on: 1. your requirements (e.g., how fast you need to be able to fetch the data from where it is stored). 2. your resources (e.g., how much money you're willing to spend on writing/updating the data).

Comment: 1. Time is not an issue, I will be saving the data once in a day. So, after I save the data on the blockchain, I can wait up to an hour if necessary for the values to be retrieved on the DAPP. 2. Ideally, I don't want to spend any amount on saving the data, but since it is not possible on Ethereum, I would like to spend as minimum as possible. The data I will be saving is for public service, sort of like charity.

Comment: Would you be able to compress this data into a small chunk?

Comment: These are prices of about 3000 items. I want to save them in a map on the Smart Contract.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101706/discussion-between-pongal-and-goodvibration).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, data is expensive if you are the one who is going to pay for it. My advice is to code a small contract that saves an ID and save the rest of the info into a database. If you want to activate a product (or a customer want to do that) you can translate that item activation to the customer. See by example the dapp blockchaincuties, use some data in local storage and other data is saved on the blockchain, the update of the blockchain data is paid by the user. I don't know what are you building, maybe you already did, but if you want It's probably better to avoid to save large data on the blockchain